# How do I submit contact form using POST request (requests & python3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm not sure if such a thing is possible, but I am trying to submit to a form such as https://lambdaschool.com/contact using a POST request.

I currently have the following code:

```
import requests

payload = {"name":"MyName","lastname":"MyLast","email":"someemail@gmail.com","message":"My message"}

r = requests.post('http://lambdaschool.com/contact',params=payload)

print(r.text)
```

But I get the following error:

```
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
```

etc.

Is such a thing possible to submit using a POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were that simple, you'd see a lot of bots attacking every login form ever.

That URL obviously doesn't accept POST requests. That doesn't mean the submit button is POST-ing to that page (though clicking the button also gives that same error...)

You need to open the chrome / Firefox dev tools and watch the request to see what happens on form submit and replicate that data in Python.

Another option would be the `mechanize` or Selenium webdriver libraries to simulate a browser and fill out the form

Comment: (For what it's worth it's my URL). I'm looking at the data in dev tools, and I copied the payload - what other elements should I copy? I'm not entirely sure what I'm seeing. The headers?

Comment: Okay, then you've programmed it not to accept the POST request

Comment: I see. I'll look into allowing POST requests.

Comment: Within the form, you've either got an AJAX event or some `action` in the HTML that points at a URL that isn't the contact page, and probably some REST API endpoint that saves to some database

Comment: @austenallred If that is indeed your URL, then you can also fix the bug that the contact form gives a confusing error message when javascript is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`params` is for query parameters. You either want `data`, for a form encoded body, or `json`, for a JSON body.

Comment: That won't fix a 405, though

Answer (score 1):

I think the url should be 'http://lambdaschool.com/contact-form'.